# How can i remove the duplicate values while using inner join

Tags: sql-server

I get duplicate AccountIDs if I use the below code.

```
Select

Distinct(BE.AccountID),

SUM(BB.Balance) AS BonusBalance,

[Freebet] = CASE WHEN be.Freebet = 1 THEN 'FREESPINS' ELSE 'BONUSDEPOSITED' END

-- INTO #bonustemp4

from BonusEarned BE

Inner JOIN BonusBalance BB

ON BE.AccountID = BB.AccountId

AND BE.BonusID = BB.BonusID

AND BE.TriggerTrans = BB.TriggerTrans

--Inner JOIN Trans T

--ON T.AccountID = BB.AccountId

group by be.AccountID , be.Freebet
```

Comment: 1) `DISTINCT` is NOT a function. 2) You must define what row (from a lot of rows with the same `AccountID`) with different `BonusBalance` and `Freebet` must be returned - then use `GROUP BY AccountID` with proper aggregate expressions over them.

Answer (score 1):

"Unexpected" duplication is *almost always* caused by incorrect Join conditions.

Work with subsets of your data to locate where these conditions are going awry.

The use of "DISTINCT" in *any* query raises a "Red Flag" with me, with it all too often being used as a way of "hiding" *exactly* this sort of duplication.

Remember that these two are roughly equivalent in terms of their query *performance*:

```
(1) select distinct x, y, z . . . ; 

(2) select x, y, z 
    . . . 
    group by x, y, z 
    order by x, y, z ;
```